How to execute a python file using SpringBoot
this is the imports of my python file called movie.py
import os
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.video.VideoClip import TextClip
from moviepy.video.compositing.CompositeVideoClip import CompositeVideoClip
import subprocess
import moviepy.config as conf
from moviepy.audio.io.AudioFileClip import AudioFileClip
import pyttsx3

this is located on resources/movie-python
i tried executing this file on the command line on its directory
python movie.py

however executing this on java returns a diffrent result
  public void callPythonFile() {
        try {
            // Directory where the Python script is located
            final File scriptDirectory = new File("src/main/resources/movie-python");


            // Command to run the Python script
            final String command = "python movie.py";

            // Start the process with the script directory as the working directory
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
            processBuilder.directory(scriptDirectory);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();


            // Read output from the process
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            // Wait for the process to finish
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            if (exitCode != 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Python script exited with non-zero code: " + exitCode);
            }
            System.out.println("Python script exited with code: " + exitCode);

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error executing Python script: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

this code freezes on the line
video_with_text.write_videofile(temp_file, codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac')

why does it has different result on manually executing the file?

I had this issue years ago. The problem is that system path settings don't work in spawned processes. So you need to use the full python path, or run console first and within that run your python script (I often did the latter)
